# Publish/Export Independent Modules in Angular

Tags: angular

I am having a business problem where i have multiple small applications running on Angular. Now Business wants to have one common Shell/application to open these small applications as modules. To be more specific i want to design a system where multiple small applications can be launch/hosted from one common application, for ex, i have Weather application, News Application and Music application built on Angular, now i want these small applications to be open from one common application much like in portlet and portal manner.

I am looking for approaches on how i can create and publish only modules from Angular and is this a good approach to implement Portlet-Portal concept in Angular.

Any reference/work/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

I think you just make it a site, and all of your existing smaller applications become different pages in your Single Page Application, they would each be a component. You could use angular client side routing to go from page to page.